# Laravel namespacing and authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with a Laravel 5.2 test site, and I'm using the built-in auth system to handle logins.

I changed the name of the app namespace to `myTest` using `php artisan app:name myTest`

However, when I submit the login form I'm still getting an error due to a namespace issue in the auth system:

```
FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 126:
Class '\App\User' not found
```

Is there somewhere I need to edit the namespace so that this will work?

EDIT: PSR4 block of `composer.json` is:

```
"psr-4": {
    "myTest\\": "app/"
}
```

Yes, I did already `composer dump-autoload` to try to refresh the namespacing, and the same issue appears.

Comment: And I'm sure you've already `composer dump-autoload`? I know there was a [bug back in `5`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/6198) for the `app:name` command causing issues but can't imagine it is related.

Comment: If you changed the namespace you need to use `myTest\User` not `App\User`

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi-- I realize that-- the question is how to make the built-in Laravel auth stuff work with a changed namespace. The code throwing the error is not mine, it's core Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `config/auth.php` file.

Check under `providers` -> `users` -> `model`.

Adjust that from `App\User::class` to your class.

Comment: I'm curious, shouldn't `app:name` handle that? It seems it hasn't but in _theory_ it should, right?

Comment: It looks, based on the content of that command (AppNameCommand@setAuthConfigNamespace), that it should change that.

Comment: @camelCase No app:name doesn't work. I use phpstorm directory option to configure this.

Comment: yea it just appears that it should.  if this solved your current issue, can you accept it so others know this resolved it.

Comment: Not sure what the issue was for you, but I tested this and I had a contributor test the command and it worked fine as expected, including changing the composer.json file and the auth config.